# Regex en javascript que seleccione algo que a sus lados (izquierdo, derecho o ambos) no tenga ciertos términos

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de encontrar una expresión regular que me seleccione aquellos espacios en blancos que a su lado izquierdo,lado derecho o ambos tengan cualesquier palabra **excepto** una palabra en especifico.

El regex debe obtener el siguiente resultado:

**Espacios internos que no debe encontrar**

- especifica especifica
- otra especifica
- especifica otra

**Espacios internos que debe encontrar**

- otra otra

Sin embargo hasta el momento el mejor resultado que he conseguido es este:
[RegExr](http://regexr.com/3ee7a)

**Edición:** Me faltó aclarar que las tildes son irrelevantes. El objetivo es suprimir todos los espacios en blanco, excepto aquellos que tengan en cualquier lado (o ambos lados) la palabra especifica. Otro modo de ver el problema es borrar todos los espacios existentes pero a la palabra **especifica** conservarle los espacios que tiene a ambos lados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías agregar un ejemplo más claro, no me quedo muy claro el contexto, podrías utilizar un párrafo más grande. y varios casos.

Comment: @cristiandev05 No se está especificando si puede haber signos de puntuación entre las palabras, o cuál es el objetivo de encontrar estos espacios (qué se hará luego). Quizás deberías aclararlo en la pregunta, en caso de que quieras una respuesta más específica. Tampoco se está aclarando si las palabras pueden contener tildes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solución

```regex
/\b(?!especifica\b)(\w+\b)(\s+)\b(?!especifica\b)/gi
```

#### Descripción

La expresión regular consume la palabra previa al espacio (y la captura en el primer grupo), y luego captura los espacios en blanco dentro del grupo 2 (`grupo[2]`).

```regex
/
\b                  # límite de palabra completa (antes de la 1er palabra)
(?!especifica\b)    # aserción (negative lookahead) para ver que no sea "especifica"
(\w+\b)             # consume la primer palabra
(\s+)               # coincide con los espacios en blanco buscados
\b                  # límite de palabra completa (antes de la 2da palabra)
(?!especifica\b)    # aserción para ver que la 2da palabra no sea "especifica"
/gi                 # g: todas las coincidencias;  i: no importa mayúsculas/minúsculas
```

Luego, usaremos la posición inicial desde donde se inició la coincidencia, y el largo de la primera palabra (`grupo[1]`) para determinar dónde inicia el espacio en blanco.

#### Código

```js
var regex = /\b(?!especifica\b)(\w+\b)(\s+)\b(?!especifica\b)/gi;
var texto = `especifica  especifica
             tres        especifica
             especifica  cuatro
             cinco       seis`;

var grupo, posInicial, posFinal, resultado = "";

while ((grupo = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    posInicial = grupo.index + grupo[1].length;
    posFinal = regex.lastIndex;
    resultado = resultado + "\n" 
              + 'Se encontró "' + grupo[2] 
              + '" desde la posición ' + posInicial 
              + ' hasta la posición ' + posFinal 
              + ' (después de la palabra "' + grupo[1] + '")';
}

document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultado;
```

```html
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

- [Demo en regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qPgKaN/1)

#### Generar el regex dinámicamente

Si se quiere generar la expresión regular dinámicamente, tenemos que asegurarnos de escapar cualquier metacaracter que pueda estar dentro de la palabra específica.

```js
function generarExpresion(especifica) {
    especifica = especifica.replace(/[\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    return new RegExp("\\b(?!" + especifica + "\\b)(\\w+\\b)(\\s+)\\b(?!" + especifica + "\\b)", "gi");
}

var regex = generarExpresion("especifica");
```

#### Eliminar (reemplazar) los espacios en blanco

Usando replace, podemos eliminar todos los espacios en blanco, excepto los que rodean a una palabra especifica. Para eso, se reemplazan todas las coincidencias (la primer palabra y el espacio) por el valor del primer grupo `$1` (sólo la primer palabra):

```js
function juntarTodo() {
    var regex = /\b(?!especifica\b)(\w+\b)(\s+)\b(?!especifica\b)/gi;
    var texto = document.getElementById("area").value;
    var resultado = texto.replace(regex, "$1");
    document.getElementById("resultado").value = resultado;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='area' rows="4" cols="60">especifica  especifica    uno        especifica  dos
   tres       especifica  cuatro        cinco       seis</textarea>
<button id='boton' onclick="juntarTodo()">Juntar Todo</button>
<textarea id='resultado' rows="4" cols="60"></textarea>
```

<kbd>[Demo en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qPgKaN/2)</kbd>

Comment: Esta solución no toma en cuenta signos de puntuación ni tildes dentro de las palabras. Se espera a que el autor pueda aclarar la pregunta.

Comment: He editado la pregunta. Tu respuesta casi logra cumplir mi objetivo sin embargo se borran partes de las palabras cuando hay más de dos en una misma linea. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozyVVp?editors=1010

Comment: @cristiandev05 El problema es en como lo adaptaste. ¿La idea es convertir `aaa    bbb especifica ccc    ddd` en `aaabbb especifica cccddd`?

Comment: Efectivamente la idea es "Juntar" todo, pero a la palabra especifica dejarle los espacios que tenga a lado y lado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás tratando de hacer se llama *lookbehind*, que sería pedirle al lenguaje que cuando encuentre lo que sí matchea (en este caso el espacio en blanco), chequee la parte anterior del regex para validarla. Lamentablemente Javascript no soporta el *lookbehind*, así que lo más cercano a lo que pedís, sería utilizar algunas de estas implementaciones o soluciones alternativas al *lookbehind* que andan por ahí:

[Javascript lookbehind (en inglés)](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2387872)

[Función JS que resuelve el lookbehind](https://coderwall.com/p/kuixxq/javascript-lookbehind)

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Y, suponiendo que por ejemplo usa [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), ¿podrías mostrar cuál sería la respuesta?